# Is there any way to update columns in other entities after updating reference entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, single-responsibility-principle

This is Project Entity which is used as reference by other entities in my project :

```
@Entity
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Project {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull private String projectName;
    @NonNull private String projectCode;
    @NonNull private String description;

    @NonNull private Integer resourceSize;

    //other fields

}
```

Another two Entities `Roster` and `OutsourceRequestForm` which copies fields `projectName` and `resourceSize` from Project Entity upon creation.

```
@Entity
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Roster {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @NonNull private String projectName;
    @NonNull private Integer resourceSize;

    //other fields

}
```

```
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
public class OutsourceRequestForm {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @NonNull private String projectName;
    @NonNull private Integer resourceSize;

    //other fields

}
```

Change to field `resourceSize` needs to be reflected in above two entities as well. 
Here is logic for that in service class updating/inserting project entities.

```
@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

    @Autowired ProjectRepository projectRepo;

    @Autowired ProjectWebClientService projectWebClientService; 

    @Autowired RosterService rosterService;
    @Autowired OutsourceRequestFormService orfService;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void updateProjectData() {
        //delete existing records
        projectRepo.deleteAll();
        //fetch data from other server
        List<Project> projectList = projectWebClientService.getProjectData(); 
        //save project data
        projectRepo.save(projectList);

        // ---->   need solution for below part   <----
        projectList.forEach(project-> {
            //find rosters by projectName and update resourceSize
            rosterService.updateRoster(project.getProjectName() ,   project.getResourceSize());
            //find orf by projectName and update resourceSize
            orfService.updateOrf(project.getProjectName() ,   project.getResourceSize());
        });
    }

}
```

Is there any way i can remove this part `projectList.forEach {}` from this class and do it at some other location in a better way as It is violating [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will also maintain Single Responsibility Principle. and You can omit the loop as well. But there is an issue in this every time you update project, it will work (if this is requirement then it is fine).

Please try this:-

```
@Entity
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
**@EntityListeners({RosterListener.class ,OrfListener.class})**
public class Project {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull private String projectName;
    @NonNull private String projectCode;
    @NonNull private String description;

    @NonNull private Integer resourceSize;

    //other fields

}
```

Listener:-

```
import javax.persistence.PostUpdate;
    public class RosterListener{

        @PostUpdate
         void onProjectUpdate(Project roject) {
            RosterService  rosterService = (RosterService ) BeanUtility.getBean("RosterService "); // find this as from your application context environment
            osterService.updateRoster(project.getProjectName(), project.getResourceSize());
         }

    }

import javax.persistence.PostUpdate;
    public class OrfListener{

        @PostUpdate
         void onProjectUpdate(Project roject) {
            OutsourceRequestFormService   outsourceRequestFormService  = (OutsourceRequestFormService  ) BeanUtility.getBean("outsourceRequestFormService  "); // find this as from your application context environment
            outsourceRequestFormService.updateOrf(project.getProjectName(), project.getResourceSize());
         }

    }
```

Comment: @Autowired, is not working Listener, so need to fetch manually bean object to update Roster and Orf

Comment: thanks for answer. can you add import  as well for PostUpdate annotation, I will check this